# JSON to Spark RDD in Python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am very new to Spark and I have been trying for a while to get Spark to understand my JSON input but I haven't been managing. In summary, I am using Spark's ALS algorithm to give recommendations. When I provide a csv file as an input, everything works fine. However, my input is actually a json, as follows:

```
all_user_recipe_rating = [{'rating': 1, 'recipe_id': 8798, 'user_id': 2108}, {'rating': 4, 'recipe_id': 6985, 'user_id': 4236}, {'rating': 4, 'recipe_id': 13572, 'user_id': 2743}, {'rating': 4, 'recipe_id': 6312, 'user_id': 3156}, {'rating': 1, 'recipe_id': 12836, 'user_id': 768}, {'rating': 1, 'recipe_id': 9237, 'user_id': 1599}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 16946, 'user_id': 2687}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 20728, 'user_id': 58}, {'rating': 4, 'recipe_id': 12921, 'user_id': 2221}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 10693, 'user_id': 2114}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 18301, 'user_id': 4898}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 9967, 'user_id': 3010}, {'rating': 2, 'recipe_id': 16393, 'user_id': 4830}, {'rating': 4, 'recipe_id': 14838, 'user_id': 583}]

ratings_RDD = self.spark.parallelize(all_user_recipe_rating)

ratings = ratings_RDD.map(lambda row:
  (Rating(int(row['user_id']),
   int(row['recipe_id']),
   float(row['rating']))))

model = self.build_model(ratings)
```

This is what I came up with after seeing some examples, but this is what I get:

```
MatrixFactorizationModel: User factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.
16/12/21 03:54:53 WARN MatrixFactorizationModel: Product factor does not have a partitioner. Prediction on individual records could be slow.
16/12/21 03:54:53 WARN MatrixFactorizationModel: Product factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.
16/12/21 03:54:53 WARN MatrixFactorizationModelWrapper: User factor does not have a partitioner. Prediction on individual records could be slow.
```

And

```
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py", line 147, in <lambda>
user_product = user_product.map(lambda u_p: (int(u_p[0]), int(u_p[1])))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Rating'
```

Can someone give me a hand? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Your error happens due to one thing.

This exception that you are suffer is about the function `predictAll` of [ALS function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.predictAll).

The issue here is that you are trying to send a Rating object to a function that need to receive a `RDD<int, int>`

I took your code and build what you need:

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating
>>> ratings = ratings_RDD.map(lambda row:
...   (Rating(int(row['user_id']),
...    int(row['recipe_id']),
...    float(row['rating']))))
>>> model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 1, seed=10)
>>> to_predict = spark.parallelize([[2108, 16393], [583, 20728]])
>>> model.predictAll(to_predict).take(2)
[Rating(user=583, product=20728, rating=0.0741161997082127), Rating(user=2108, product=16393, rating=0.05669039815320609)]
```

Your JSON is not wrong, what you are having is a problem when you call `predictAll` that you are sending a `Rating` object instead of a `RDD<int, int>`